# Why is the working directory with Eclipse / Maven set to the project directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, working-directory

The standard output directory for Eclipse / Maven compiled code (+resources) is `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` for compiled test-code (+resources).

If you run your code (through Eclipse's run configuration), the default working directory is the project's directory.

Why is it handled like that instead of using the individual `classes` / `test-classes` folders? E.g. if I create a new file, it is created in the project directory. Doesn't it make more sense if it would be created in the `classes` / `test-classes` folder?

I for myself changed all working directories but was wondering if there is a good reason to keep the working directory at base project level.

Comment: because those folders are in the target folder, which is meant to disappear at each clean and meant to only keep temporary files, its content can potentially change at each build + you don't put under your version control the folder and its content

Comment: *changed all working directories* Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Tunaki E.g. when logs are created (or other files) while in development, they end up in `PROJECT-DIR/logs/app.log`, but I prefer them in `PROJECT-DIR/target/classes/logs/app.log`, so they are removed with each clean instead of clogging up my project base dir.